# How to pass data array from controller to view in defined js variable?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How can I pass `$data array ['1']` from a controller to a view in a defined js variable `serial=$(this).val();`?

**In Controller::**

```
public function add_video() {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `video_category`";
  $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `video_sub_category`";            
  $data['1'] = $this->madmin->avideo_category($query);
  $data['2'] = $this->madmin->avideo_sub_category($query1);             
  $this->view_page->admin_page('v_add_video', $data);           
}
```

**In View::**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change_category").change(function(){
        serial=$(this).val();// $data['1'] will be added here
    })
    $("#change_sub_category").change(function(){
        serial=$(this).val();// $data['2'] will be added here
    })        
})
```

Comment: If you have data in PHP that needs to be given over to the client-side, you'd need to develop an API and endpoints that javascript can access through AJAX. Here's an example: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Comment: You could add as data html5 variable and use in view. Documentation http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Are you trying to do this: `serial = <?php echo $data['1']; ?>;` ?

Comment: if i don't use any array then it takes 2nd data as serial .... but if I use  $this->view_page->admin_page('v_add_video',  $data['1']);  then it takes the 1st value ... but need to take both data to their respective function

Comment: FelippeDuarte i just tried ur suggestion but no luck ... still don't pass

Comment: I think Felippe is correct here. If the data is a string, you should add quotation marks:  serial = '<?php echo $data['1']; ?>';  you just need to think about how the JS is written *after* the PHP is executed.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte is correct when the fixed data pass from php to javascript. But if you use function or array then it does not work. For this reason you have to use Ajax